# Get a single value from an Object returned in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, get, observable

I have service that gets all the data from the database and in the component , I am not able to return a single value from the object it is returning.Following is to get data in the service. I want to display the 'email' only from the firestore in the HTML.

```
getProfile(id:string) {
  return this.db 
  .collection<dataModel>('dataColl' )
  .doc(id)
    .ref.get()
    .then(function(doc) {
      return doc.data();  .
    });
  
 }
}
```

In the component

```
  const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");     
  this.dataService.getProfile(id).then(data => {
  console.log(data.email);
```

HTML

```
 <div *ngIf= "data">
Email: {{data.email | async}}
```

**Doesn't display anything on the HTML page**

Comment: What do you get if you log only `data`?

Comment: @MishaMashina in the console log I have getting the single email if that I want to display in html, but not rendering from the html page.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed.

```
const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");     
  this.dataService.getProfile(id).then(data => {
  this.data = data;
  console.log(data.email); 
})
```

HTML

```
 <div *ngIf ="data" >
    Email: {{data.email}}
  </div>
```